# Does one party get primary challenges at a higher rate than another party?

Tags: united-states, election, primaries

Does one party get primary challenges at a higher rate than another party?

If this question is not directly answerable, what criteria would I use to determine this rate?

Comment: I think that virtually all notable elections have primarily challengers, it's just that most of the time the primary challengers are not notable and don't have a hope of winning.

Comment: Good point @DavidGrinberg. The primary challenges that stick out are the ones that are shocking or significant, like a legitimate challenge to a many-term incumbent. That is in contrast with say a primary challenge from "crazy Dave" who runs in every election because he is bored.

Comment: @Freiheit - "crazy Dave" who's bored... ironically, that's how many described Trump at the start of the primary :)

Comment: Supposedly [Getting Primaried: The Changing Politics of Congressional Primary Challenges (Legislative Politics and Policy Making)](https://www.amazon.com/Getting-Primaried-Congressional-Challenges-Legislative/dp/0472035851) by Robert G. Boatright studied this.